# Traefik and self-signed SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, traefik

Noob to Traefik and Docker. I have prepared a self signed certiicate using:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout www.example.co.uk.key -out www.example.co.uk.crt-days 365
```

In my traefik.toml file I have:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/www.example.co.uk.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/www.example.co.uk.key"
```

However this results in:

```
traefik          | time="2019-06-17T22:11:17Z" level=debug msg="Serving default cert for request: \"www.example.co.uk\""
traefik          | time="2019-06-17T22:11:17Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:57770: tls: no certificates configured"
```

If I omit the cert definitions so that traefik.toml reads as:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
  #  [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
  #  certFile = "certs/www.example.co.uk.crt"
  #  keyFile = "certs/www.example.co.uk.key"
```

I get the dummy cert provided by Traefik and it works great but I just want to wrap my head around why my defined certs are not being used.

In my docker-compose.yml I believe I have mounted the correct volume:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
  - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
  - /var/www/docker/certs:/certs
```

And the certs reside at `certs/` relative to my `docker-compose.ym`l and `traefik.toml` files. Permissions seem good as well both owned by root - the `crt` having 644 and `key` having 600.

How can I use a self-signed cert instead of Traefiks defaults?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a path mismatch, particularly with some paths relative and others absolute. Try the following in your compose file (relative path to local certs):

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
  - ./certs:/certs
```

And then switch to an absolute path in the toml (leading slash on certs):

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/certs/www.example.co.uk.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/www.example.co.uk.key"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.  I didn't need the leading slash in the toml file in the end. One thing I wanted to confirm - when mounting a file use an absolute path and when mounting a directory use a relative path - is this a good rule of thumb?

Comment: @Zakalwe when the source is within your project, relative to the compose file, use a relative directory. When it is in the specific location on the host, use an absolute path. For the destination inside the container, use an absolute path. And for configuration files inside the container, that depends on whether you know what WORKDIR is set to and how the app handles that.

Comment: Ah! Seems obvious but it's only when someone points it out explicitly out does it truly make sense! Thanks again!

Comment: why no stores field is defined ?

Comment: What "stores field"? Note that it's been 3 years from this answer and traefik has changed a lot since then.